# Publish dll - copy to bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll

MVC project.
On my data access layer I have a `libs` folder where I store some dlls that the project needs t oaccess data. One of them is set "copy local" to true. The goal is to copy the dll to the bin folder so I can deploy it with the application.

The thing is, when I build the app, it does copy to the bin folder, but to the bin folder on the DAL project only. Since it is a web applicaiton I want to build the web project and have the dll copied to its bin folder so I can just deploy it withou having to manually coping it from the bin on the dal to the bin of the deployed appliation.

What do I need to do to accomplish that?

Comment: Post build event, add a copy of the dll.

Comment: Why can't you just reference it in your Web project?

Comment: reference a data access dll on the web project? doesnt look right...

Answer (score 1):

Build Action = Content might help; but then it will only come in to your DAL Bin if it is referenced there.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the web project and than click on Deployment project as given below ..this will add all required dll for your project in the path of your poject which you can see in ouput window

[image]